# Is there a financial instrument that is exposed to the change in growth of an asset over time?

Tags: options, finance, quant-trading-strategies, trading, financial-engineering

Is there a financial instrument that is exposed to the rate of change of the value of a specific asset? If I believe a stock price will continue to grow in the future, but grow more slowly than in the past, is there an instrument that exists that will allow me to profit from that?

-If I purchase a publicly-traded stock, I am exposed to the value (price on secondary exchange) of that stock over time. Mathematically the value "V(t)" of that asset could be expressed as a function of the price "P(t)" over time "t".

-If I buy an option I am exposed to the change in the price of that asset over time but in a linear fashion. Mathematically: V(t) = P(t) - P(t0)  (for a call option with strike price P(t0))

-Is there an instrument whose value is the rate of change of the value of the price over time? Mathematically:  V(t) = dP(t)/dt
I understand the price of an asset is obviously not continuous, so a derivative may not be the correct operation, but intuitively this is how I think of it.

Please respond if you have any answers, comments, or if my question indicates I do not understand what I am talking about. I've tried to be accurate in my description, but please let me know if could have worded it better.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Hello. It seems to me (but I don't know if this meets your requirements) that if you think the return on an asset will be low, you would like to be the payer on a total return swap (TRS).

Comment: @noob2 Thank you for your response!
I just tried to educate myself on TRS, these seem more like a way to increase your leverage on the gain (or losses) of an asset. Is this correct?

Comment: You seem to be interested in a log contract?

Comment: @Kermittfrog Thank you for your response! Do you mean Discreet  Log Contract for cryptocurrency? That is the only thing that comes up for me. I would be very grateful for a link if you have one!
Thank you again!

Comment: For example this here: https://www.risklatte.xyz/Articles/QuantitativeFinance/QF12.php - does it meet your ideas/requirements?

Comment: @Kermittfrog Thank you. I think I need to do some more learning before I can evaluate if this is what I am looking for.